# How can I transfer multiple files+folders at once from the Acrobat app on iPadOS to Windows?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, itunes, adobe-acrobat, ipad

iTunes on Microsoft Windows doesn't see that the iPad is connected to my computer via USB:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do this with Drop Box and that works very well.

Comment: Thanks, good idea!